# memory leak with dynamicdatadisplay vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, charts, memory-leaks

I’m currently using DynamicDataDisplay for displaying spectrum on User Interface, it works great but has a huge memory leak (about 1-2MB/cycle). It seems that it doesn't release all of the memory when I update it with a new graph. Did any one else experienced this problem? and how would I go about solving it?
Thanks in advance. See my code below

```
Dim P1Chart As New Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter()
Dim P1ChartDateTime As New Windows.Controls.Label()

…………………….

‘First remove old line graph from chart
ClearSpectrum(iTabIndex)

‘Load arrays with new spectral data
For SpectCtr = 0 To ScanElements
   If Spectrum = ScanType.Absorbance Then
      x(SpectCtr) = SpectCtr * 0.5 + 800.0 ‘Convert to wavelength if absorbance spectra
   Else
      x(SpectCtr) = SpectCtr
   End If

   y(SpectCtr) = sr.ReadLine()
Next

Dim xDataSource = AsXDataSource(x)
Dim yDataSource = AsYDataSource(y)

Dim xyDataSource As New CompositeDataSource(xDataSource, yDataSource)

Select Case StreamNumber
Case 1
   P1Chart.AddLineGraph(xyDataSource, Colors.Red, 1, “Probe A”)
   P1ChartDateTime.Content = String.Format(“Time: {0}, X-Axis: {1}”, FileSaveTime, xAxisTitle)
Case 2
   P2Chart.AddLineGraph(xyDataSource, Colors.Red, 1, “Probe B”)
   P2ChartDateTime.Content = String.Format(“Time: {0}, X-Axis: {1}”, FileSaveTime, xAxisTitle)
End Select

………

Private Sub ClearSpectrum(ByVal iTabIndex As Integer)
Dim nIndex As Integer

Select Case iTabIndex
Case 1
   For Each child1 As IPlotterElement In P1Chart.Children
      If TypeOf child1 Is Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.LineGraph Then
         RemoveList.Add(child1)
      End If
   Next

For Each child1 In RemoveList
    P1Chart.Children.Remove(child1)
Next
……………..
RemoveList.Clear()
```

Comment: If it is WPF, you should add that tag

Comment: you could try calling Garbage Colector with GC.Collect() and the end of the sub

Comment: How have you determined that you have a memory leak?  What tool did you use?

Comment: Thank you for Garbage Collector suggestion Jaxedin. It reduced the memory leak roughly by half, but Unfortunately it still there.

Comment: Chris  Dunaway: I use Process.GetCurrentProcess() method to grab WorkingSet each cycle and then write that to a file. After I graph the log, it's pretty clear that there's increase in memory usage overtime